# Existence of open subgroup extending a smaller one

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, abelian-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian topological group and $H \subseteq G$ a dense subgroup (equipped with the subset topology). Furthermore let $V \subseteq H$ be a subgroup that is open in $H$. Does there exist a subgroup $U \subseteq G$ that is open in $G$ and such that
$$
U \cap H = V
$$
holds?

Of course, by definition of the subset topology there is an open *set* $U'$ such that this holds, but I am having trouble seeing if we can choose $U'$ to be a subgroup. One approach could be to let this set $U'$ be as stated and then let $U$ be the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $U'$. (This is formed by taking all the sums and inverses of elements in $U'$.) Then $U'$ is automatically open, but to show that $U' \cap H = U \cap H$ I am having difficulties. In fact I am not even sure if its true!

If someone could tell me whether this is true, either by a (sketch of a) proof or by counterexample, that would be amazing. Feel free to impose additional hypotheses on the topology, for example:

- $G$ is locally compact;
- $G$ has a "subgroup topology", i.e. there is a basis of open neighborhoods of the identity that is formed by open subgroups;
- $G$ is profinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subgroup $\overline V\supset U’$ of $G$ has non-empty interior, hence it is open. :-)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I do not see how this answers the question though, could you elaborate a little? Thank you!

Comment: @Joachim $\overline{V}$ is the subgroup you asked about. Indeed, it is a subgroup (as the closure of the subgroup $V$), it is open because it contains a non-empty open set $U'$ and $\overline{V}\cap H=V$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. However, we do not necessarily have $U' \subseteq \overline{V}$ I think. All we know is that $U'$ is some open subset of $G$ and that $U' \cap H = V$. Why does it follow $U' \subseteq \overline{V}$?

Comment: For the rest I agree, so if we would fix this last thing the question is solved!

Comment: @Joachim A set $U'\setminus\overline{V}$ is open, being non-empty it should contain a point of $h\in H$ (recall, that $H$ is dense in $G$). Then $h\in (U'\cap H)\setminus \overline{V}=V\setminus \overline{V}$, a contradiction.

Comment: That solves it indeed, thanks!